# Restrict Banner numbers in CMS Hybris

Tags: spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a RotatingImagesComponent and allocating banners to that component.
As per requirement , need to allow maximum 6 banners in RotatingImagesComponent.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this ?
Do I need to create CMS restriction in this case ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Below are the steps to Restrict Banner Numbers.

1 Extend RotatingImagesComponent to create custom one.

```
<relation code="SimpleResponsiveBannerComponentToTestRotatingImagesComponent" localized="false">
            <deployment table="BannerToTestRotImgRel" typecode="25003"/>
            <sourceElement qualifier="rotatingComponent" type="TestRotatingImagesComponent" cardinality="many"/>
            <targetElement qualifier="simpleResponsiveBanners" type="SimpleResponsiveBannerComponent" cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" ordered="true"/>
</relation>
        


<itemtype code="TestRotatingImagesComponent" extends="RotatingImagesComponent" jaloclass="com.company.testcore.jalo.components.TestRotatingImagesComponent">
<description>Image carousel</description>
</itemtype>
```

2 Create new controller to set banneers based on your custom logic.

```
package com.company.teststorefront.controllers.cms;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.model.components.SimpleResponsiveBannerComponentModel;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.company.testcore.model.components.TestRotatingImagesComponentModel;
import com.company.teststorefront.controllers.ControllerConstants;

/**
 * Controller for the TestRotatingImagesComponent{@link TestRotatingImagesComponentModel}
 */
@Controller("TestRotatingImagesComponentController")
@RequestMapping(value = ControllerConstants.Actions.Cms.TestRotatingImagesComponent)
public class TestRotatingImagesComponentController
        extends AbstractAcceleratorCMSComponentController<TestRotatingImagesComponentModel> {
    private static final String IMAGE_CAROUSEL_BANNERS_ATTRIBUTE = "imageCarouselBanners";
    private static final int BANNERS_MAX_SIZE = 5;

    @Override
    protected void fillModel(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, TestRotatingImagesComponentModel component) {
        //@formatter:off
        List<SimpleResponsiveBannerComponentModel> limitedBannerList = component.getSimpleResponsiveBanners().stream()
                .limit(BANNERS_MAX_SIZE)
                .collect(toList());
        //@formatter:on
        model.addAttribute(IMAGE_CAROUSEL_BANNERS_ATTRIBUTE, limitedBannerList);
    }
}
```

3 create testRotatingImagesComponent.jsp and have logic to render banners.

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="ycommerce" uri="http://hybris.com/tld/ycommercetags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="image" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/image"%>

<div class="owl-carousel js-owl-carousel js-owl-banner carousel-banner" data-autoplayspeed = "${component.timeout}">

    <c:forEach items="${imageCarouselBanners}" var="banner" varStatus="status">
        <c:if test="${ycommerce:evaluateRestrictions(banner)}">
            <c:url value="${banner.urlLink}" var="encodedUrl" />
            <div class="carousel__item">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="${encodedUrl}"<c:if test="${banner.urlLink}"> target="_blank"</c:if>>
                    <image:damImgModel damAsset="${banner.media}" cssClass="carousel-banner__image"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

4 control this variable **BANNERS_MAX_SIZE** dynamically by adding in properties and use configurationService.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need in an interceptor
Create interceptor that implements PrepareInterceptor

```
public class RotatingImagesComponentInterceptor implements PrepareInterceptor<RotatingImagesComponentModel> {
   ....
   @Override
   public void onPrepare(RotatingImagesComponentModel model, InterceptorContext ctx) throws InterceptorException {
      if (CollectionsUtils.isNotEmpty(model.getBanners()) && model.getBanners().size() > 6)
         throw new InterceptorException("Only 6 banners are allowed");
   }
}
```